# Find the duration of a playlist in Apple Music

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-music, playlist

How can I find the duration (in hours/minutes) of a playlist in Apple Music?

Comment: Could you explain a bit what playlist and what OS you are trying to calculate? iTunes v12 on OS X shows this in the playlist window clearly..

Comment: A playlist in Apple Music on an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.